# Check variable conditions in template [or,and]

Tags: mysql, django-templates

I need to make if statement in html template.

Working:

```
{% if field == 'var_1' or field == 'var_2' %}
```

but i can't compare rendered variable with None or ' '

```
{% if field == 'var_1' or field == 'var_2' and 'var_3' != '' %}
```

last statement is not working.

var_3 in mysql is NULL or contains varchar(200)

What is proper solution to handle this?

Comment: `field == 'var_1' or field == 'var_2' and 'var_3' != ''` is equivalent to `field == 'var_1' or (field == 'var_2' and 'var_3' != '')`

Comment: note that `'var_3' != ''` will always be true.

Comment: @Cid template is rendered by Django

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for the isnull() function.

This function returns True if passed a value set to NULL

.....AND NOT IsNull(var3) AND....